# Award rest of bounty after expiration, but minimum bounty is raised

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I put a 50 point bounty on a question. A user gave a great answer, but I was busy and didn't get a chance to confirm the answer before the bounty expired. As per standard procedure, the user's answer, which had received two votes, was given half the bounty (25).

Fine. But the user deserves the full 50 point bounty, because it wasn't their fault that I was busy with other things. I'd like to award the other 25 points. But you'll tell me I can't, because that's the rules.

OK, fine, so those are the rules. So I decided to create *another* 50 point bounty (remembering that 50 points is the minimum bounty) on the question, just so the user could get at least what they were promised. But wait; now 50 points is no longer the minimum. Stack Overflow is now forcing me to put up a 100 point bounty!

The new, raised minimum is the part I don't understand. Maybe there is some reasoning behind it, but that reasoning is probably based on the assumption that the new bounty is to attract attention (and if the first bounty didn't attract attention, the new one should be higher). But in this case, that is a faulty assumption: I'm wanting to create a bounty to make sure the user providing an answer got what they deserve. But they don't deserve (or at least I don't want to pay :) ) in total three times what I originally promised just to make sure they get paid what I originally promised..

Comment: Why the minimum spend doubles each time: [“Abusing” bounties for unlimited profit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)

Comment: I agree with the thinking here. The problem just happened to me: stackoverflow.com/questions/41922521/…. I think the system should be adjusted so that moderators can be allowed to step in on one-off cases like this and manually reward the bounty balance to the deserving Answerer when the original poster does not come back to the thread or doesn't have time to verify the answer before the bounty period expires.  As I don't think this situation happens often enough to warrant special coding, I suggest providing moderators special ability to manually award expired bounty balances in such cases.